# How can I display the data created?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm sending a data ...

```
....
        // upload on file select or drop
        $scope.upload = function (file, id) {
            id = typeof id !== 'undefined' ? id : null;
            Upload.base64DataUrl(file).then(function(base64){
                //auth
                var fbAuth = FirebaseURL.getAuth();
                //Ref
                var ref = FirebaseURL.child("users_photos");
                ref.push({'image': base64,'removed': true, 'user_id': fbAuth.uid, 'dt_created':Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP ,'dt_updated':Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP}, function(error){
                    if (error) {
                        alert('Error');
                    } else {
                        var newID = ref.key();

                         //I would like display data insert here?
                         console.log(DATA RESULT INSERT);
                    }   
                });
            });
```

I would like display data inserted.

It is possible to display the last inserted object without query by the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use AngularFire for synchronized collections.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)

Create a query using `limitToLast(1)` to always sync the last inserted object.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase)
  .factory('userItems', UserItems)
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function UserItems($firebaseArray, rootRef) {
  return function userItems(uid) {
    var itemRef = rootRef.child('items');
    var query = itemRef.orderyByChild('uid').equalTo(uid);
    return $firebaseArray(query);
  }
}

function MyController($scope, userItems, rootRef) {
  $scope.items = userItems(rootRef.getAuth().uid);
  $scope.addItem = function addItem(item) {
    $scope.items.$add(item).then(function(ref) {
      var record = $scope.items.$getRecord(ref.key());
      // save the data to the other structure
    });
  };
}
```

[See the section on Complex queries for more info.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries)

Comment: Interesting, but in this case I'm making a query the last item.

Is there a risk of returning the wrong record, if there are many insertions at the same time?

I did some testing with AngularFire (answer below), is it more secure or the query don't have problem with many inserts the same time?

Comment: var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
   list.$add(data).then(function(ref) {
    var id = ref.key();
    var rec = list.$getRecord(id);
    console.log(rec);
   });

Comment: Are you looking for the user's last item, rather than the last item?

Comment: So, I would like get the saved object. Not necessarily the last item.

When push/add/set, I get the key, but I want to get the object saved in firebase after send.

Comment: Ah that's a bit different than "the last record". If you're using a `$firebaseArray`, then the object will appear in the array after being inserted. What is it that you're looking to do with this object?

Comment: This object will be inserted into another structure. First saved in a table with all the uploaded data ("log/event table").

I get the saved object to another structure. I believe we could save only  the key, but it is a project requirement.

Comment: path /users_photos
type Photos {
  image: String,
  user_id: String,
  removed: Boolean,
}


path /contents 
type Contents {
 text : String, 
 ...
 photos: Map<String, Photos> | Null
}

Comment: Ah I see. Then yes, using the `ref` in the .`then()` block is totally fine. I've updated my answer to indicate this.

Comment: last doubt, this code "var itemRef = rootRef.child('items'); var query = itemRef.orderyByChild('uid').equalTo(uid); return $firebaseArray(query);" It is the same to do this "var q = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1); q.once("value", function(snap) { console.log(snap.val());});"

Comment: No. The first query will return all the items for one user. The second will return the last item at the location. You can add `limitToLast(1)` to the first to get the last item added by the user.